# Python: import email subject from outlook by clicking on a certain email

Tags: import, outlook, onmouseclick

I can´t find any code in python code to import the subject of an email from outlook if the user is clicking on a certain email.
Any ideas if this is possibe and if can you please help me with the code.
Thank you very much

the typical import such as messages.GetLast()